# How can you abandon TFS code reviews in bulk?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-code-review

We moved to using Git and PRs... then we moved to Azure DevOps from on-premise TFS.

Our developers still have a number of old, irrelevant code reviews in their **Assigned to me** section.

I tried following the directions here
 [How can you cancel a Code Review Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158956/how-can-you-cancel-a-code-review-request/49159512) but using that method I was unable to set the **Closed Status** field. The edits would not save.

Answer (score 1):

That's when I stumbled across a UI feature to simply **Edit** the items in the query.

[image: Right-click the selected work items and select the Edit option in the context menu.]

Then we can set the **State** to **Closed** and the **Closed Status** to **Abandoned**.

[image: Set the state to closed and set the closed status to abandoned.]

Then click **Save Items** in the query menu, refresh the query, and they're all gone now.

[image: No results for TFS query]